# How to set up web firebase web

Tags: firebase, flutter

I was trying to set firebase for and I follow all the procedures. But After running the app it went all white and showed this error

```
 ‘TypeError: Cannot read property ‘app’ of undefined’ In Flutter Web
```

I then went on to google to search for solution and did everything the way they asked but I ended up having the null safety error. After that I remove the null safety and this is now the error I am getting

```
Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57090/YI8fSoqgm_w=/ws
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at Object.u [as app] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js:1:18836)
    at Object.app$ [as app] (http://localhost:57026/packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart.lib.js:31:101)
    at new cloud_firestore_web.FirebaseFirestoreWeb.new (http://localhost:57026/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:934:64)
    at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:57026/packages/cloud_firestore_web/src/write_batch_web.dart.lib.js:834:73)
    at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:57026/packages/tembea/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:18:46)
    at main (http://localhost:57026/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:31:35)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:57026/dart_sdk.js:40666:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:57026/dart_sdk.js:40697:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:57026/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:30:18)
    at http://localhost:57026/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:57026/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
    at Object.runMain (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8452:21)
    at http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:24130:19
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4461:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11511:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4425:20)
    at main__closure3.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:24142:16)
    at main__closure3.call$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:24069:19)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4823:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12879:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12826:14)
    at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12416:19)
    at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12362:15)
    at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12695:12)
    at _MapStream._handleData$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12756:12)
    at _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12721:20)
    at Object.eval (eval at Closure_forwardCallTo (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1701:14), <anonymous>:3:44)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4823:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12879:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12826:14)
    at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12416:19)
    at _ControllerSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12362:15)
    at _SyncStreamController._sendData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12201:32)
    at _SyncStreamController.add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12082:15)
    at Object.eval (eval at Closure_forwardInterceptedCallTo (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1781:14), <anonymous>:3:45)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4823:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12879:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12826:14)
    at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12416:19)
    at _ControllerSubscription._add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12362:15)
    at _SyncStreamController._sendData$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12201:32)
    at _SyncStreamController.add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12082:15)
    at _GuaranteeSink.add$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23581:25)
    at HtmlWebSocketChannel_closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:23874:60)
    at _EventStreamSubscription_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:18042:26)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4829:16)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12879:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12826:14)
    at _CustomZone_bindUnaryCallbackGuarded_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:13016:25)
    at invokeClosure (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1524:26)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (http://localhost:57026/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1543:18)
```

Below is my main function

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
```

And the pubspec

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
  firebase_core: ^1.8.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.4
  provider: ^6.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
```

Finally the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="tembea">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>tembea</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAQYkB8TMTJKMmdzmjVQwsyiQrfMaXqOao",
    authDomain: "tembea-4d3c6.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "tembea-4d3c6",
    storageBucket: "tembea-4d3c6.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "909705170922",
    appId: "1:909705170922:web:d034fefe33c9d0d2026c93",
    measurementId: "G-11NNW6J10N"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know what I may have done wrong. Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two seperate imports for Firebase, which may cause issues. Remove your `<script type="module">... import...</script>` and replace it with the different style of initialization like this:

```html
<script>
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAQYkB8TMTJKMmdzmjVQwsyiQrfMaXqOao",
    authDomain: "tembea-4d3c6.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "tembea-4d3c6",
    storageBucket: "tembea-4d3c6.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "909705170922",
    appId: "1:909705170922:web:d034fefe33c9d0d2026c93",
    measurementId: "G-11NNW6J10N"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

This is currently recommended way that can be found in [Flutter Firebase docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web).

Since you are initializing Firebase in the main function you may also want to move your app startup script below the script of Firebase initialization.